# installation problem in windows 8(inbuilt)

Tags: installation, grub2

i installed ubuntu 13.10 in windows 8 using unebootin and making my usb drive bootable. it installed completely but after rebooting, windows 8 started again without giving me option to choose my os.  i restarted my laptop and opened boot order using f9 key. it shows ubuntu but after hiting enter, ubuntu did not started. it showed some black screen like command prompt giving option like

grub>

it did not worked. i wrote 'exit' there to get out of there. 
please tell me if there is any way to open ubuntu. otherwise tell me how to delete that installed ubuntu.
i am not able to uninstall that ubuntu as it has decreased my laptop's speed.... ????

Comment: change `UEFI` mode to `legacy mode` in bios.Then try boot-repair disk.

Comment: how to try boot-repair disk

Answer (score 0):

1.Log in into your windows 8 os.Download and install EasyBCD from [*`here`*.](http://www.softpedia.com/progDownload/EasyBCD-Download-45820.html)

2.Under linux section add a boot entry for your Ubuntu Partition and set the bootloader to `grub2`.
And also add entry for your windows 8 partition.

3.reboot

OR

Download [`boot-repair`](http://sourceforge.net/projects/boot-repair-cd/files/) live disk.Make a bootable boot-repair live usb using unetbootin software in windows,reboot and change the boot-order in bios to usb.Once the live disk was boot up click on the option `Recommende Repair`.It will reinstall your grub.